# SyntaxError while i am running the folowing

Tags: python

I am using this in python

```
df = data[['customerId', 'transactionDateTime', 'transactionAmount', 'posEntryMode',
                                            'isFraud']]
df = df.sort_values(by= 'customerId','transactionDateTime').reset_index(drop=True)
```

and it gives me the following error :

```
SyntaxError: positional argument follows keyword argument
```

how can i resolve this issue ?

i am expecting to shor the values on the basis of the customeId and the transactionDateTime

Comment: The problem is you doing `df.sort_values(by='customerId', 'transactionDateTime')`. That's not valid syntax. I dont know enough about pandas to help you further though

Answer (score 2):

```
df = df.sort_values(by='customerId','transactionDateTime').reset_index(drop=True)
```

Here, you're giving two arguments: `by='customerId'` (the keyword argument), and `'transactionDateTime'` (the positional argument). Python prevents you from giving a positional argument after a keyword argument.

Did you mean to do this instead?:

```
df = df.sort_values(by=['customerId','transactionDateTime']).reset_index(drop=True)
```

In this case, there's only one argument: `by=['customerId', 'transactionDateTime']` (a list of strings), rather than two arguments (both strings).